# Remove other device admins using Samsung Knox

Tags: android, samsung-knox

I want to prevent factory reset in the Samsung tablet. I tried with Knox APIs (Standard SDK) they help (in settings, and through h/w l\keys) but they don't help a lot like factory reset by Android Device Manager. Is there any way to prevent installing apps that have device admin permission? If it is already installed Knox should remove it then disable/uninstall or whatever. Note: I shouldn't be disabling installation of applications